# WebRTC: createOffer's success callback called twice in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I'm playing with [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) and following [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/?redirect_from_locale=ru) article. Now I experiencing strange behaviour in Chrome (Mozilla work fine) - when I call [createOffer](http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#widl-RTCPeerConnection-createOffer-void-RTCSessionDescriptionCallback-successCallback-RTCPeerConnectionErrorCallback-failureCallback-MediaConstraints-constraints) I pass a success callback (named RTCSessionDescriptionCallback in W3C draft) in and then strange thing is that in Chrome this callback get called twice! This leads [setLocalDescription](http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#widl-RTCPeerConnection-setLocalDescription-void-RTCSessionDescription-description-VoidFunction-successCallback-RTCPeerConnectionErrorCallback-failureCallback) to be also called twice and first it succeed but second call return error:

```
failed to set description SetLocalDescription failed: Failed to push down offer transport description.
```

So can any one suggest why this happens on chrome (I use version 31.0.1650.63)?

[Here is the plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1nE1aactrREDs8hRUywt?p=preview) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already expected that this was a problem with `onnegotiationneeded` and yes. When you change  line 37 to `console.trace`, you can see which code called your function `createOffer()`:

[image: console.trace]

What you want to do is create and set an offer first, and then add the onnegotiationneeded. This will prevent any errors.
[As you are following a tutorial, see this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/MarijnS95/P567K/)