# Concurrent local offers cause error

Tags: webrtc

In my application I heavily use renegotiation to add and remove local streams. Unfortunately, the use of renegotiation may drastically increase the number of race conditions when offers and answers are exchanged.

Let's consider the following scenario :

> ```
> create a local offer without any local stream              -- success 
> setLocalDescription(offer)                                 -- success  
> user grant access to the video which causes renegotiation  -- success 
> create a local offer with  local stream                    -- success
> setLocalDescription(offer)                                 -- failed
> ```

The error thrown is :

```
Failed to set local offer sdp: Failed to push down transport description: Failed to set local identity.
```

- If the statusSignal is "have-local-offer" I cannot call setLocalDescription?
- What should be the right way to handle this situation?
- I was thinking to delay the second offer ( containing the new local stream ) until  the first answer/offer handshake is completed. This is not an optimal solution, but it should work. What do you think ?

[More info](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/tLwUoRB0Vug)

Comment: If your website changes streams all the time this won't be helpful, but for the scenario described above the easiest would be to send only one sdp, after the user 'granted access to the video'.

Comment: The video and audio toggling is implemented add and removing the stream ( this is the correct way to implement this mechanism). This is the cause why I am encountering this issue.

Comment: I believe there was something to clear the sdp or to overwrite it. I will take a look at some old code to find out how I did it.

Comment: That would be awesome. I cannot figure out how to overwrite or revert the sdp after it has been installed. According to the standard webRTC there should be a rollback mechanism, but this, to my knowledge, has not yet been implemented. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know [from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061650/webrtc-createoffers-success-callback-called-twice-in-chrome/21144553#21144553) that it is not handy to attach the negotiation event handler directly as this wil trigger it twice (I don't know if that is in your case). What I tried was attaching the handler **after** I have successfully sent and received the SDP data. Then I caused negotiations by adding and removing streams and that works perfect. Also make sure that when you receive an SDP object you create a `new RTCSessionDescription(<receivedObject>)` and then append that to `pc.remoteDescription`.

Comment: I am aware of the problem. I solved it checking the status of IceConnectionState. if IceconnectionState === new, skip renegotiation.

Comment: @GiuseppePes that is also a smart idea to check whether a reconnection can be made. Is your problem solved now?